# How to set Progress bar for loading data in activity android

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set Progress bar for loading activity with data in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11079676/how-to-set-progress-bar-for-loading-activity-with-data-in-android)

This is my first class where Url loding .

```
public class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

         @Override
         public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
         view.loadUrl(url);
         return true;
         }
    }
```

This is my Activity Class where data is displacing in web view.

```
public class detailedview extends Activity
{
    WebView mWebView;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.detailedview);
        GetSet gs = new GetSet();

        String title = gs.getTitle();
        String desc = gs.getDesc();

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setTextSize(TextSize.SMALLER);
        mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", "<p  align=\"justify\"><b> " + title+"</p></b><p align=\"justify\"><br>"+ desc + "</p></br>", "text/html", "utf-8", "");
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
    }
}
```

i want to put progress bar for loading data in my activity i have tried much but not able to do .

can u please write code or post code so that i can apply progress bar for loading data according to my code.

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/11079676/1289716

Comment: yes , i have tried much but not able to do some problem is coming please help me post whole code according to my code so that i can put progress bar

Comment: see your previous Que. i have edited answer

Comment: Look here, this thread seems to answer your question: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537454/android-webview-progress-bar